# Extract sub-matrices with connected values and restricted direction

Tags: r, matrix

My previous [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42URm.png) about extracting sub-matrices with connected cells has been solved out. There are some desired matrices containing different groups of cells which need to be further subtracted (matrices with green and red border on the fig).
The logic to subtract the groups in the two desired matrices is:

- desired matrices have >= 3 columns
- starting at the first group of rows in the first column in the desired matrix (yellow cells in id2 col or red cells in id5
- selecting all adjacent cells in the increasing columns on the right (yellow cells in id3 or red cells in id6 and then id7) and finishing the first sub-matrix of the desired matrix (*).
- returning to the next group of rows (green cells in id2 or pink cells in id5) in the first column and do (*) for the second sub-matrix of the desired matrix.
- repeating so until the last group of rows in the first column

The output is data frames of coordinates of cells which belong to each sub-matrix (separated by colors).

In put:

```
time <- c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43)
id2 <- c(NA,-23.08,-23.08,-23.08,NA,-23.08,NA,NA,NA,NA,-23.08,-23.08,-20.63,-18.03,NA,-16.67,-16.67,-18.03,NA,NA,NA,NA)
id3 <- c(-24.62,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-23.08,-23.08,-23.08,-23.08,NA,NA,NA,NA,-18.33,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-21.67,-23.33)
id4 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-6,-6,-2,-23.33,-23.33,NA,NA)
id5 <- c(NA,NA,NA,-10,NA,NA,-10,-10,NA,-4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
id6 <- c(-10,-10,-10,NA,NA,-10,NA,NA,-10,NA,-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
id7 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,-6.25,NA,-10,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(time, id2, id3, id4, id5, id6, id7)
```

Output:

```
row col matrix
1   3   1
2   2   1
3   2   1
4   2   1
1   6   2
2   6   2
3   6   2
4   5   2
6   2   3
7   3   3
8   3   3
9   3   3
10  3   3
11  2   4
12  2   4
13  2   4
14  2   4
15  3   4
16  4   4
17  4   4
18  4   4
19  4   4
20  4   4
16  2   5
17  2   5
18  2   5
21  3   6
22  3   6
6   6   7
7   5   7
8   5   7
9   6   7
10  7   7
10  5   8
11  6   8
12  7   8
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Henrik. I have edited the question following your suggestion. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: Further questions: You write: "starting at the first group of rows in the _first column_ in the desired matrix"; But `time = 11 & id6` is _not_ in the _first_ column? "selecting all adjacent cells in the _increasing columns on the right_; moving from `time = 11 & id6` to `time = 13 & id5` is not selecting cell in  _increasing columns on the right_? Please clarify the logic ;)

Comment: I meant the first _group of cells_ in the first column in the desired matrix. Because _time = 11 & id6_ are not in the first column of the desired matrix, so ignore that cell and include it to the matrix constructed by the two cells at _time = 13, 15 and id5_ .